# Main domain is redirecting to subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I've a domain `domain.com` and made one sub domain 'forum.domain.com'. I'm using `Apache2` and added one `A record` to the dns records and made `virtualNameServer` as:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName forum.domain.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/vanilla
   <Directory /var/www/vanilla>
      # This relaxes Apache security settings.
      AllowOverride all
      # MultiViews must be turned off.
      Options -MultiViews
      allow from all
   </Directory>

   ErrorLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /etc/httpd/logs/vanilla-error.%Y-%m-%d.log 86400"
   CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /etc/httpd/logs/vanilla-access.%Y-%m-%d.log 86400" "%h %l %u %t %D \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""

</VirtualHost>
```

In the sub-domain, I've installed `Vanilla Forum Software`. But, now the problem is, whenever I go to `http://domain.com` or `http://www.domain.com`, it goes to `http://forum.domain.com`. There is `.htaccess` by default in `forum.domain.com`:

```
# Original
# If you modify this file then change the above line to: # Modified
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   # Certain hosts may require the following line.
   # If vanilla is in a subfolder then you need to specify it after the /. 
   # (ex. You put Vanilla in /forum so change the next line to: RewriteBase /forum)
   # RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php\?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

Using Name-based Virtual Hosts

Main host goes away

If you are adding virtual hosts to an existing web server, you must also create a  block for the existing host. The ServerName and DocumentRoot included in this virtual host should be the same as the global ServerName and DocumentRoot. List this virtual host first in the configuration file so that it will act as the default host.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm completely new in this area. Again many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need two virtual hosts, in your example, this would look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName forum.domain.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/vanilla
   <Directory /var/www/vanilla>
      # This relaxes Apache security settings.
      AllowOverride all
      # MultiViews must be turned off.
      Options -MultiViews
      allow from all
   </Directory>

   ErrorLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /etc/httpd/logs/vanilla-error.%Y-%m-%d.log 86400"
   CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /etc/httpd/logs/vanilla-access.%Y-%m-%d.log 86400" "%h %l %u %t %D \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName domain.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/main

   ErrorLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /etc/httpd/logs/domain-error.%Y-%m-%d.log 86400"
   CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /etc/httpd/logs/domain-access.%Y-%m-%d.log 86400" "%h %l %u %t %D \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""

</VirtualHost>
```